# Creating Jenkins Slave On Windows 2008 R2 Box

Tags: java, windows, jenkins

I have a master Jenkins server. I would like to create a slave Windows 2008 R2 slave Jenkins?

Do I need to install Jenkins on the slave box? Or is saving slave-jnlp file to disk and opening it enough?

I downloaded the slave-agent.jnlp and tried running it. I get:

[image]

Comment: I have the same error on a windows 7 professional 32-bit.

Comment: I am able to launch the jnlp file with the following command line : `java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://myjenkins -secret <my_secret>`. But I am unable to get the GUI so I can't install the jnlp as a windows service.

Answer (score 1):

You don't install the full Jenkins server on the slave. Just the slave agent per this documentation: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Howdoesthiswork%3F

Answer (score 0):

Well, which part of [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) did you follow? There are many ways of doing it

- Did you try [installing as a service](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service#InstallingJenkinsasaWindowsservice-InstallSlaveasaWindowsservice%28require.NET2.0framework%29)?
- Did you try using [Java Webstart](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-LaunchslaveagentviaJavaWebStart)?

Comment: I tried both. I think it's an issue with Windows 2008 R2 64bit as described here: http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/JIRA-JENKINS-11856-Jenkins-Slave-fail-to-start-on-Windows-2008-R2-64-bit-as-windows-service-td4103240.html

Comment: To run Jenkins as a service on a Windows 2008 R2 64bit or later, the OS requires the jenkins-slave.exe to run as an administrator.  The later versions of Jenkins will automatically perform this task when you install the slave.  Check the properties for your jenkins-slave.exe file.  

 - Right click on jenkins-slave.exe
 - Go to properties
 - Go to the Compatibility tab
 - Towards the bottom, make sure that *Run this program as an administrator* is clicked

Answer (score 0):

This is because Java security related to **jnlp** has increased, preventing it from using http.

Option A) Secure method: Switch to HTTPS. Either buy and install a certificate, or even create your own Certificate Authority and self-sign your own certificate, install it, and install the CA as a trusted root on all nodes! Should work now.

Option B) Copy the `slave-agent.jnlp` file from the Jenkins server to the Jenkins node by some secure means, such as SSH, or for those who don't care about security (peer pressure, that):

```
wget http://10.150.0.150:8080/computer/NODENAME/slave-agent.jnlp
```

or via an administrative Powershell (also insecure transfer):

```
iwr('http://10.150.0.150:8080/computer/NODENAME/slave-agent.jnlp')
```

Set your Jenkins node to trust any insecure http that looks like it might be from your Jenkins server:

```
Windows > All Programs > Java > Configure Java > Security tab > Edit Site List
add your server ("http://10.150.0.150:8080", for instance)
```

double-click 'slave-agent.jnlp' file on desktop.
Should see a Jenkins UI saying slave agent started.

```
File > Install as Windows Service
```

Highly recommend HTTPS (Option A.)